# UML tool supporting collaboration

Tags: uml, collaboration-diagram

I am looking for an UML modeling tool (e.g. uml designer, papyrus, modelio or such) with a support for **collaboration** diagrams (as described here : http://www.uml-diagrams.org/collaboration-diagrams/collaboration.html and here http://www.uml-diagrams.org/collaboration-diagrams/collaboration-use.html)

I am especially interested by the ability to draw this kind of schema:

[image: collaboration use]

I would also appreciate it if somebody could link me to a good tutorial about this.

PS : To give some context, I am mostly interested in collaboration diagrams in order to describe which part of a class diagram are taking part in a given design pattern (from example which classes of a class diagram are the observer/subject of an observer pattern).

Comment: MagicDraw is fully conformant with UML 2.x.

Comment: I am pretty sure that most of the tool support this notation. You could check papyrus or modelio for free...

Comment: @RedBeard I did but could'nt figure out how to create collaboration use in practice.

Comment: I guess you have to learn/test it for each tool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a composite structure diagram under Modelio, you have to:

1. Create a project.
2. Select UML root project under the model explorer.
3. Create a Class.
4. Select the created Class and create a Composite Structure diagram.

The following screenshot show the required steps.

[image]
[image]
[image]